# Visual basic not executing lines

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I have a piece of code in visual basic that is supposed to encrypt 16 byte blocks one by one, encode them in base64 and return a string containing all the encoded and encrypted blocks:

```
Private Function EncryptARIA(plaintext As String) As String
    Dim aria As ARIA = getAria()

    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim buffer As Byte() = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext)
    Dim blocks As List(Of Byte()) = getByteBlocks(buffer)
    Try
        For Each block As Byte() In blocks
            result = result + Convert.ToBase64String(aria.Encrypt(block))
            'For Each bits As Byte In block
            '    Console.WriteLine("[DEBUG] input byte: " + bits)
            'Next
        Next
        Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The code is not decrypting correctly and I wanted to see the plaintext bits going in and the decrypted and decoded bits going out in another method, the issue is that whenever I un-comment the for in the code, the function starts returning nothing, what is going on?

Comment: Perhaps it's erroring - you're swallowing any errors.  Put some logging in the catch block, or remove it entirely.

Comment: You are right, there was an error because I was trying to concatenate bits as a string instead of using: 
Console.WriteLine("[DEBUG] input byte: {0}", bits)
Thank you!